# mscorlib exception

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2008

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my web app based on following exception?  I am getting this when I try to run this project from VS2008:

```
    System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled
  Message="Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed."
  Source="mscorlib"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
       at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
       at MS.Internal.PresentationFramework.SecurityHelper.DemandUnmanagedCode()
       at System.Windows.Window..ctor()
       at System.Windows.Application.GetAppWindow()
       at System.Windows.Application.ConfigAppWindowAndRootElement(Object root, Uri uri)
       at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Please see comments for my updates.
Just added one more edit.

Comment: Can you show the code for the thread that was running at the time of exception? I can see that some Window is being shown/invoked which is a WPF that correct? That window was triggering a permissions exception for some reason...also the code for that window as well please...

Comment: How do I see code running at time of exception?  All I see is:
Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.InitializeComponent'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code
'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.GeneratedApplication'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code
'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.InitializeComponent'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code
'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.GeneratedApplication'
Step into: Stepping over non-user code'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedApplication.InitializeComponent'

Comment: I'm surprised this is going near xaml for a normal web application. Are you sure this is not a WPF / Silverlight app?

Answer (score 0):

See if you have the permission to execute unmanaged code... If not, grant it, and then try again...

I reckon this is going to a setup where your rules have arsed up for some reason...

Martin.

Comment: How do I do this?  I found one link describing how to do this with following code, but I'm looking for a simpler solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0313z05.aspx

Comment: Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Microsoft .Net Framework Configuration.

Have a look at the execution policy - there seems to be a "Run unmanaged code" section in there - not sure how to edit it though - just tried and failed myself...

Comment: Thank u for your response!  I found the Execution tab in multiple places under Permission Sets for Runtime Security Policy.  But all of these are Read-only.  And it is set to "No" for all of these.  How do I edit Permission sets?

Comment: It's not something I've done either... Perhaps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c9c2y1w.aspx could be of help...